# Electrocardiography simulator

Tags: beginner, c

I am tring to learn coding in clear way. I developed easy application to simulate EKG. I would like to ask some experts, if the code is clean and if they have any suggestion, what could I improve. Possible improvment is not to avoid first loop (no counter of data is set to -1, to avoid first read), but I do not have an idea how to make it.

### EkgDataModel

```
struct ekgDataModel {
    int amountOfData;
    int frequency;
    float newValue;
    float previousValue;
};

void initEKGData(struct ekgDataModel *ekgData) {
    // -1 to avoid first loop
    ekgData->amountOfData = -1;
    ekgData->frequency = 0;
    ekgData->newValue = 0;
    ekgData->previousValue = 0;
}
```

### EkgFunctionality.c

```
void runElectrocardiography() {
    struct ekgDataModel ekgData;
    initEKGData(&ekgData);

    while (ekgData.newValue != END_VALUE) {
        analyzeNewValue(&ekgData);
        ekgData.previousValue = ekgData.newValue;
        ekgData.newValue = getNewInput();
    }
}

void analyzeNewValue(struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
    if (ekgData->newValue >= MIN_INPUT_RANGE && ekgData->newValue <= MAX_INPUT_RANGE) {
        ++(ekgData->amountOfData);
        ekgData->frequency += checkCrossing(ekgData);
        checkIfFrequencyValid(ekgData);
    }
}

void checkIfFrequencyValid(struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
    if (ekgData->amountOfData == MAX_AMOUNT_OF_DATA
        && (ekgData->frequency < MIN_FREQUENCY_ALLOWED
                || ekgData->frequency > MAX_FREQUENCY_ALLOWED)) {
        displayWrongFrequencyMessage(&ekgData->frequency);
        ekgData->frequency = 0;
        ekgData->amountOfData = 0;
    }
}

int checkCrossing(struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
    if (ekgData->newValue * ekgData->previousValue < 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

### EkgInputOutputOperations.c

```
float getNewInput() {
    float newValue;
    scanf("%f", &newValue);
    return newValue;
}

void displayWrongFrequencyMessage(int *frequency) {
    printf("Bad frequency result: %d\n", *frequency);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of things that might help you improve your code.

### Arrange functions from simple to compound

Within your source code files, try to arrange your functions such that simpler functions, such as `checkCrossing` precede compound functions such as `analyzeNewValue` that call other simple functions.  Doing so allows you to avoid having to write function declarations that would otherwise be required.

### Use `const` where practical

The `checkCrossing` function is passed a pointer to an `ekgDataModel` and the function does not alter that structure.  This should be made explicit by declaring the parameter `const` as in:

```
int checkCrossing(const struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
```

### Carefully consider your data

The `checkCrossing` routine is looking for zero-crossings and uses this expression:

```
if (ekgData->newValue * ekgData->previousValue < 0) { /* ... */ }
```

However, consider the possibility that one of the samples is exactly 0.  For example, a sequence might be -0.15, 0.0, +0.20.  For (-0.15, 0.0) the expression is false and for (0.0, +0.20) the expression is again false.  The effect is that the function has just missed an obvious zero-crossing. An alternative approach would be to use the [`signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/signbit) macro:

```
if (signbit(ekgData->newValue) != signbit(ekgData->previousValue)) { /* ... */ }
```

I'd rewrite the function using `stdbool.h` as a `bool` function:

```
bool isZeroCrossing(float prev, float curr) {
    return (bool)signbit(curr) != (bool)signbit(prev);
}
```

### Prefer `>=` to `==` to prevent "runaway data"

In the `checkIfFrequencyValid` function, the program currently does this:

```
if (ekgData->amountOfData == MAX_AMOUNT_OF_DATA
    && (ekgData->frequency < MIN_FREQUENCY_ALLOWED
            || ekgData->frequency > MAX_FREQUENCY_ALLOWED)) {
     /* stuff */
     ekgData->amountOfData = 0;
}
```

There is a potential problem here in that the `analyzeNewValue` function only increments `amountOfData`, so if it ever gets to `MAX_AMOUNT_OF_DATA` and the `frequency` is within range, subsequent readings will increase `amountOfData` beyond `MAX_AMOUNT_OF_DATA` which would make for a difficult-to-debug error.  Instead, use the `>=` operator for the first clause to make sure that you don't have "runaway data" problems.

### Use better names

Function names such as `displayWrongFrequencyMessage` and `initEKGData` are good because they give a very good idea of what the functions are doing just by the name.  However functions like `checkCrossing` and `checkIfFrequencyValid` are not so good.  In one case, essentially a boolean value is returned indicating that a zero crossing has occurred, but in the other, nothing is returned at all.  Better for boolean functions is to name them to suggest what the return value might mean.  For example `isZeroCrossing` would return `true` if it detected a zero crossing.  Very clear and doesn't require much further explanation.

### Check return values of standard functions

Many standard functions, including `scanf` can fail and return values that can help in detecting those failures.  To write robust software, you should get into the habit of checking the return values and dealing intelligently with the potential failures.

### Avoid `scanf` if you can

There are so many [well known problems with `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) that you're usually better off avoiding it.  The usual approach is to read in user input into a string and then parse from there, in this case using something like `atof()`.

### Think carefully about `signed` versus `unsigned`

Would it ever be possible that `amountOfData` or `frequency` would be negative numbers?  If so, what would that mean?  Better would be to declare them both as `unsigned` so that all possible values have an interpretable meaning.

### Prefer pass-by-value for simple data

Generally, unless there is a need to modify the underlying variable, it's better to pass a value rather than a pointer.  For instance, this function:

```
void displayWrongFrequencyMessage(int *frequency) {
```

Could instead be written like this:

```
void displayWrongFrequencyMessage(int frequency) {
```

That way there's no way that the function could alter the original frequency variable and it's likely to be efficiently passed in a register.

### Write code for humans to read it

The `runElectrocardiography` function is not bad, but it's not easy to understand.  I'd recommend doing something like this instead:

```
void runElectrocardiography() {
    unsigned dataCount = 0;  // number of data points so far
    unsigned crossingCount = 0; // number of zero-crossings 
    float curr; // the most recent EKG voltage value 
    float prev = 0; // the previous EKG voltage value 

    for (curr = getNewValue(); curr != END_VALUE; curr = getNewValue()) {
        if (isWithinValidRange(curr)) {
            ++dataCount;
            if (isZeroCrossing(prev, curr)) {
                ++crossingCount;
            }
            if (!isFrequencyValid(dataCount, crossingCount)) {
                displayWrongFrequencyMessage(crossingCount);
                dataCount = 0;
                crossingCount = 0;
            }
            prev = curr;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `ekgDataModel` structure is no longer needed or used.

Comment: Good catch/suggestion on `checkCrossing()`.

Comment: @chux: I'm actually a little concerned about the use of `signbit`.  I haven't yet located anything that says it will always return the *same* value for all negative number; just that it's an integral value that will evaluate to `true`,  As such the use of `!=` is still bothering me.  To be pedantic, maybe it should be `return !signbit(prev) != !signbit(curr);`.  What do you think?

Comment: Agreed , convert the result to T/F or 1/0 is better. Maybe like `((bool)signbit(prev) != (bool)signbit(curr))`.  I like to avoid negations: Don't you dislike the inversion of negative logic too often, no?

Comment: @chux: I've updated my answer to incorporate that.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Wow, fantastic work Edward, thank you very much. I must say that I don't know some of the function/names you used, but that's good motivation to get to know them. I will reconsider my code and ask if I got any more problems. Thank you once again.

Comment: I've studied your code and in "Write code for humans to read it" you decided to remove structure ekgDataModel. Actually this structer was my recent idea, because it seemed quite logic, to wrap those bits together and pass together. But on the other hand, some functions did not need all the structure's fields. Perhaps I got my mind too much on object oriented programming and encapsulation concept.

Comment: There's nothing inherently *wrong* with using a `struct` to collect related data.  In fact, I often recommend it.  It just didn't seem to me to add that much value here; when I refactored the code, I noticed I simply didn't need it so I left it out.  It could be that as you do more with the data, you'd want to reintroduce it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int checkCrossing(struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
    if (ekgData->newValue * ekgData->previousValue < 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

For that sort of thing, you can do

```
int checkCrossing(struct ekgDataModel* ekgData) {
    return (ekgData->newValue * ekgData->previousValue < 0);
}
```

Because `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`. So there is no need to use "if x is true return true if x is false return false"-style statements.

I understand why you did it, though:

```
ekgData->frequency += checkCrossing(ekgData);
```

Replacing this with `+= true` just looks weird!

So if you want to keep things clear, what you'd do is this:

```
if(checkCrossing(ekgData)){
    ++(ekgData->frequency);
}
```

Comment: First tip sounds very resonable, although when it comes to second one, values can be either positive numbers or negative one. So "checkCrossing" is simply checking, if multiplication brings minus upfront. Thank you for you time!